# Split Python DF Columns into 2 based off a predefined list of options

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
print(df):

Text
John Smith abc def ghi jkl
Michael Smith abc def ghi jkl
Liz Jones abc def ghi jkl
```

I also have a predefined list of people who i want to find and split the above contents into two columns.

```
names = ('John Smith','Michael Smith','Liz Jones')
```

I am hoping to get the following:

```
print(df):

Name             |          Information
John Smith       |        abc def ghi jkl
Michael Smith    |        abc def ghi jkl
Liz Jones        |        abc def ghi jkl
```

i have tried:

```
df['Name','Information'] = df['Text'].str.split(names)
```

but i think the str.split needs a string and doesnt take a list of names. Is there anyway to split columns off a defined list?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with joined all names by `|` for regex or and then for all another values:

```
names = ('John Smith','Michael Smith','Liz Jones')

df = df['Text'].str.extract(f'(?P<Name>{"|".join(names)})(?P<Information>.*)')
print (df)
           Name       Information
0     John Smith   abc def ghi jkl
1  Michael Smith   abc def ghi jkl
2      Liz Jones   abc def ghi jkl
```

If want remove this column and add all another columns for original use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(df.pop('Text').str.extract(f'(?P<Name>{"|".join(names)})(?P<Information>.*)'))
```

Or:

```
df[['Name','Information']] = df.pop('Text').str.extract(f'(?P<letter>{"|".join(names)})(.*)')
print (df)

            Name       Information
0     John Smith   abc def ghi jkl
1  Michael Smith   abc def ghi jkl
2      Liz Jones   abc def ghi jkl
```